# Integration of Python flask server and a File system

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am doing a project. It is using a File system(1GB File) rather than a database. I created the front end using angular. I wrote a Python-Flask-Server that handles the requests from the client( Browser) and dispatches the respective html files. However, I want to save all the users( Username and Password) regestered  in a 1GB file for server side storage. Where should I start now?.  Any resources ? Please help.

Comment: I created a 1GB file using the following code:
    def filecreate():
    f = open("E:\\sample.txt", "wb")
    size = 1073741824 # bytes in 1 GiB
    f.write("\0" * size)

Comment: Why exactly are you using a 1gb file as a database? If you insist on that I would look at _mmap_ for faster file read/writes.

Comment: No specific reason. But wanted to use filesystem rather than a database . This is my main project.

Comment: `Where should I start now` : setup a database